# Unexpected token ILLEGAL when using setTimeout/Cleartimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what i want: Timeout when i hover out of a div, cancel if i hover on top of the div again.

The code works if i remove the cancelfunction. So showing and hiding the div works fine.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var timeoutID;
        function clearAlert()
        {
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        }​

        if ($('.txtVote').text() == "Avgi stemme")
        {
            $('#starInfo').hover(
            function ()
            {
                clearAlert();
                $('#CarDetailsButtons').css('right', '10px');
                $('#voteStars').show();
            },
            function ()
            {
                console.log("hide iniated");
                timeoutID = window.setTimeout(hideStars, 2000);
                console.log("hide executed");
            });     
        }

        function hideStars()
        {
            console.log("hideStars ran");
            $('#CarDetailsButtons').css('right', '45px');
            $('#voteStars').hide();
        }
});
```

And, this is my error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

which appears on the line right after `window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);`

Anyone able to see what I'm doing wrong? :)

**EDIT:** **WORKS**

So, it seems i had some kind of copy paste bug. I wrote the function clearAlert manually, just like it was before, and it works now.

Thanks for all the input!

Comment: `var timeouteId;` versus `timeoutID` - change one of them

Comment: Did not work :( but i updated the code. Still the same error. I doubt i even need the var timeoutID;

Comment: Move the var to global scope: `window.timeoutID="";`

Comment: Added window.timeoutID=""; but still dosnt work

Comment: Try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s9YFr/).

Comment: See my edit for solution. Thanks anyways guys :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var that = this;
that.timeoutID = null;

...

that.timeoutID = ...
```

OR

you have to declare var timeoutID = null; global. So you have the var in a gloabl context and not within the function-context of $(document).ready.

the best solution ist to write a little js-class with the timer in it. so you have no global conflicts an it works.

greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to move your functions outside of doc ready like this:

```
function hideStars()
    {
        console.log("hideStars ran");
        $('#CarDetailsButtons').css('right', '45px');
        $('#voteStars').hide();
    }

function clearAlert()
    {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    }​

$(document).ready(function ()
  {
    var timeoutID;


    if ($('.txtVote').text() == "Avgi stemme")
    {
        $('#starInfo').hover(
        function ()
        {
            clearAlert();
            $('#CarDetailsButtons').css('right', '10px');
            $('#voteStars').show();
        },
        function ()
        {
            console.log("hide iniated");
            timeoutID = window.setTimeout(hideStars, 2000);
            console.log("hide executed");
        });     
    }


});
```